# Query multiple tables for common fields and then order by 1 common field

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables (blog,news,photos).

All tables have the following common fields (id, pub_date, title).

I want to check the 3 tables for the latest piece of published content, and i also want to get the id, title and pub date, and ideally know from which table is each piece of content (ie blog,news etc)

This is what I have, it produces this error - Unknown column 'b.pub_date' in 'on clause'")

```
SELECT b.id, b.pub_date, b.title,\
    n.id, n.pub_date, n.title,\
    p.id, p.pub_date, p.title FROM
    blog b,\
    news n,\
    photos p\
    JOIN n ON b.pub_date = n.pub_date\
    JOIN p ON b.pub_date = p.pub_date\
    WHERE b.is_published=1 AND n.is_published=1 AND p.is_published=1\
    ORDER by b.pub_date LIMIT %s", [limit]);
```

Besides the fact it might bring up questionable issues regarding model design, how can I get the information i need from the query?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Your JOIN syntax is not correct, it should be:

```
FROM blog b
JOIN news n ON b.pub_date = n.pub_date
JOIN photos p ON b.pub_date = p.pub_date
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually solved this with some help on IRC, props to Plushy and Twist- on #sql

```
    SELECT id, pub_date, title FROM blog WHERE is_published=1\
    UNION\
    SELECT id, pub_date, title FROM news WHERE is_published=1\
    UNION\
    SELECT id, pub_date, title FROM photos WHERE is_published=1\
    UNION\
    ORDER by pub_date LIMIT %s", [limit]);
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure I advised you to use UNION ALL :) Also, add something like `'blog' AS type` in the `SELECT` list.

Comment: True, union all is more performant and dupes are not an issue.  If you want to answer this question I'll accept.  Thanks,